# Wrong class view method being called in flask app

Tags: python, if-statement, flask, try-catch

I have this weird behaviour I see in my flask app where I generate a URL for one view only to have it call another view. Tried to trace the issue but can't put my finger on it.

Here is the class views:

```
@admin_blueprint.route('/admin/<string:manage_admins>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
@fresh_login_required
def admin_manage_admins(manage_admins, admin_id=None):
    """
    Used to managed all the registered
    admins by the super admin or the developer
    """
        # TODO finish this
    admin = Admin()
    form = AllAdminsProfile(object=admin)
    include_name = 'manage_admins'
    admins = Admin.query.all()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        try:
            # TODO update the edited admin using 'id'
            return redirect(url_for('admin.admin', admin_id=admin_id))
        except TemplateError as err:
            print(err)
    return render_template('admin.html', page_title='Admin Dashboard', dashboard_name='Haiflytrap Dashboard', include_name=include_name, form=form, admins=admins)

# INFO Optional route that might be included in the future
# @admin_blueprint.route('/admin/<string:customers_orders>', defaults={'order_id': ''}, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@admin_blueprint.route('/admin/<string:customers_orders>', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def customer_orders(customer_orders):
    # order = CustomerOrder()
    # form = OrderForm(object=order)
    if customer_orders == 'customers_orders':
        try:
            orders = CustomerOrder.query.get()
            include_name = 'customers_orders'
            # if customers_orders_form.validate_on_submit():
            #     # TODO add query to update on item
            #     orders = CustomerOrder.query.get(order_id).first_or_404()
            #     customers_orders_form.populate_obj(object=orders)
            #     db.session.commit()
            #     return redirect(url_for('admin.admin'))
            return render_template('admin.html', page_title='Admin Dashboard', dashboard_name='Haiflytrap Dashboard', include_name=include_name, orders=orders)

        except TemplateError as err:
            print(err)
```

The html link that should call `def customer_orders()` but it calls `def admin_manage_admins()` instead:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('admin.customer_orders', customers_orders='customers_orders') }}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action my-btn-secondary">Customer Orders</a>
```

And this is the `admin.html` template used:

```
{% extends 'admin_layout.html' %}
{% block content %}
  {% if include_name == 'dashboard' %}
    {% include 'dash_landing.html' %}  
  {% endif %}
  {% if include_name == 'manage_admins' %}
    {% include 'manage_admin.html' %}  
  {% endif %}

  {% if include_name == 'profile' %}
    {% include 'profile.html' %}  
  {% endif %}
  {% if include_name == 'password_update' %}
    {% include 'password_update.html' %}  
  {% endif %}
  {% if include_name == 'customers_orders' %}
    {% include 'customers_orders.html' %}  
  {% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id say its because your urls are the same -
they both resolve to `admin/some_string`
So when the url is entered flask just resolves the first one.

If you changed your customer orders url to:
`@admin_blueprint.route('/admin/customer-orders/<string:customers_orders>', methods=['GET'])`

it should make a difference

Comment: I thought the string value mattered and not just that it is a string!

Comment: It does, for your function, but in this case how can Flask differentiate between the 2? Its looking for a url related to that function and it gets back `admin/<dynamic_string>` so it goes to the first url that matches.

Comment: Interesting, thank you now I know why some of my links where acting funny!